# how can I share an app using skype?

Tags: skype

Does Skype allow app or desktop sharing?  If so, how?

Comment: Skype shares using the same method that MSN Live messenger can share a desktop.   You can share desktop as read-only or interactive depending on how you configure it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[It does in it's newest version 4.1](http://www.skype.com/intl/en/allfeatures/screensharing/)

**Screen sharing**

*Share your desktop with friends – for free.*

Sometimes trying to explain what you are seeing on your screen to someone on a call just doesn’t work. With screen sharing you can easily show exactly what you are looking at by simply calling your Skype contact and sharing all or part of your desktop.

*How screen sharing works*

To share your screen simply call a contact and in the conversations window click Share > Share Your Screen in the IM toolbar (in Windows) or Share > Share Screen (on a Mac). You can even select if you want to share your full screen or just a part of it.

The person you are sharing your screen with can see your screen in full screen mode. And best of all, you can continue talking via Skype whilst you share your screen.

**You’ll need our latest versions of [Skype for Windows](http://www.skype.com/intl/en/download/skype/windows/) and Skype for Mac OS X to use screen sharing.**

Answer (score 2):

(Disclaimer, I'm on Yuuguu Dev Team)

If you want to use remote control or share to multiple contacts, you can use [Yuuguu](http://www.yuuguu.com/features/skype-integration) which integrates with Skype and is also available as a Skype Extra.